# how can i just show the lines which contains the searched string in textarea Java?

Tags: java

This is my code snippet. Instead of printing in console how can i refine in text area itself. I tried `textarea.write(line)` but throws an error.

```
public void search() {
    hilit.removeAllHighlights();

    String s = entry.getText();
    if (s.length() <= 0) {
        message("Nothing to search");
        return;
    }
    Scanner in = null;

    in = new Scanner(textArea.getText());
    while(in.hasNext())
    {
        String line=in.nextLine();

        if(line.contains(s)){
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    }
```

Comment: which error do you get?

Comment: How can the length of a string ever be less than 0???

Comment: without entering an user tries to search a string then the length less than zero works

Comment: Error thrown is The method write(Writer) in the type JTextComponent is not applicable for the arguments (String)

Comment: I got the answer.. i just appended the text area after every line. textArea.append(lineFromFile + newline );